# Who is specifically targeting me?

Tags: support, serial-voting

I want to know who disliked me so much? I came to know that I was specifically targeted by someone on Physics Stack Exchange. So please let me know who that was.

Comment: Honestly, looking over your Physics questions that are still visible, they seem poorly researched and overly broad. Are you sure you're being targeted and not that your questions are just inappropriate for the site?

Answer (score 15):

For one thing, this isn't [Physics Stack Exchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com). This is Meta, which is the support and discussion site for the whole of the Stack Exchange network. If you're having a problem specific to that site, the proper place to ask is at https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com.

However, voting is anonymous. No one knows who voted on your question(s) except the people who cast the votes. Moderators can't even see that information. Developers can look at the raw database, but they seldom do unless there's significant fraud.

If it's a whole series of your posts that have been downvoted, that's "serial voting" and will be reversed by an automated process. (See [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126829/21960))

If it's simply that one or more of your posts have received a number of downvotes, please note that people vote on the *content* of questions and answers, *not* the person who posted. You're not being "attacked". People simply feel that your contribution is not good. If that's the case, that's something you might want to bring up on the [site's Meta](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/) to see how you can improve the content. Before that, though, I suggest reviewing the advice at [How to Ask](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). You'd also do well to make sure your question fit's the [site's scope](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). If, after all that, you find people judging your content is not something you want, then Stack Exchange isn't for you; you should find somewhere else to get your questions answered.